# Сложности прямой речи

Tags: прямая-речь

По правилам слова автора после прямой речи, представляющие собой отдельное предложение, отделяются от нее точкой и тире. Получается, предложение должно выглядеть так:

– Береги Сашеньку, пожалуйста. Ты ему мила, он тебя послушает. - Саша покраснел. - Когда с батюшкой своим встретишься, попроси, чтобы Сашеньку не обидели.

Или все-таки так (как ремарку):

– Береги Сашеньку, пожалуйста. Ты ему мила, он тебя послушает. (Саша покраснел.) Когда с батюшкой своим встретишься, попроси, чтобы Сашеньку не обидели.

А как быть, допустим, в таком случае:

– Петр Иванович, батюшка твой (Она видела, как Саша вздрогнул) воевал под...

Или еще одна сложность - как оформить попутные мысли человека в прямой речи другого (точку ставить внутри скобок или за скобками):

– В России же со слугами без плетки обращаться нельзя. («Либерал с арапником», – зло прошептал Саша.) Моль, дрянь беспросветная, человечки, – опять по-русски добавил граф и зыркнул на холопов.

Answer (score 1):

Согласно правилам, текст автора, не относящийся к говорящему лицу и непосредственно следующий за прямой речью, выделяется в ***новый абзац:***

- Я уверен, - продолжал я, - что княжна в тебя уж влюблена.
  ***Он покраснел до ушей и надулся.***(Л.).
  Такое оформление слов автора (в скобках) при прямой речи встречается обычно в стихотворении. Когда прямая речь, прерванная авторскими словами (ремаркой), является продолжением предыдущей (тире ставится справа, в конце строки):

  ```
  Ты много требуешь, Эмилия! - 
              (Молчание)
  ```

  Кто бы мог подумать, что такой глупец,

  ```
  Такой бесчувственный...чудна природа!...(Л.)
  ```

  (***Справочник-практикум. Д.Э. Розенталь)***.
  В вашем случае, слова автора в скобках будут выглядеть как вставное предложение, внося в основное предложение дополнительные сведения. Что не совсем уместно при прямой речи.

Comment: Здесь после слов автора нет продолжения прямой речи.

- Я уверен, - продолжал я, - что княжна в тебя уж влюблена. 
Он покраснел до ушей и надулся.(Л.)

А в моих примерах, в чем и сложность, есть.

– Береги Сашеньку, пожалуйста. Ты ему мила, он тебя послушает. (Саша покраснел.) Когда с батюшкой своим встретишься, попроси, чтобы Сашеньку не обидели.

– Петр Иванович, батюшка твой (Она видела, как Саша вздрогнул) воевал под...

Comment: Нашел. (Цитирую по Розенталю): Если слова автора, стоящие после прямой речи, представляют собой отдельное предложение, то они пишутся с прописной буквы.
 - Скорей, загорелась школа!  - И он побежал будить людей. 
Вы можете применить один из указанных способов. Выбирайте сами!

Comment: Самое интересное, что это правило все знают и пример из Розенталя уже кто только не приводит везде. А вот в живом примере из живого текста трудно расставить знаки.

– Петр Иванович, батюшка твой (Она видела, как Саша вздрогнул) воевал под...

Comment: Этой информации действительно нет. Поэтому лучший выход - составить для себя конспект применяемых форм и ссылаться на них. А эти формы достаточно разнообразны и интересны.

Answer (score 1):

1) – Береги Сашеньку, пожалуйста. Ты ему мила, он тебя послушает. - Саша покраснел.- Когда с батюшкой своим встретишься, попроси, чтобы Сашеньку не обидели.

В этом случае смело можно ставить тире, распространенный вариант.

2) Здесь можно использовать вставную конструкцию:

– Петр Иванович, батюшка твой (она видела, как Саша вздрогнул) воевал под...

3) Здесь можно оставить скобки или поставить тире:

– В России же со слугами без плетки обращаться нельзя. - «Либерал с арапником», – зло прошептал Саша. - Моль, дрянь беспросветная, человечки, – опять по-русски добавил граф и зыркнул на холопов.

Comment: Такое оформление с тире возможно, но слова должны начинаться со строчной буквы.Назовите, пожалуйста, справочник, где дается такое оформление.

Comment: Без справочника,Серж. Такое оформление с тире широко применяется в  литературе.Например: - Суперсекретное? Неужели? - Лэнгдону вспомнился масонский перстень, который П. Соломон гордо носил на правой руке. - Тогда почему масоны не таясь носят знаки отличия - перстни, броши, булавки?

Comment: Я искал в справочниках, но не нашел. Поищу в Интернете, может, найду.

Answer (score 1):

Варианты со скобками встречал раза два в жизни. Зато случаи, где ставиться точка, а затем слова автора начинаются с заглавной буквы, повсеместно. Они в изобилии представлены в художественной литературе. Переводы книг Стивена Кинга издательством "АСТ" имеют множество примеров таких диалогов.

— Пр. — Ав. — Пр.

Нигде не удалось найти правила, разрешающего или запрещающего писать таким образом. Однако, полагаю, редакторы имеют веские основания использовать эту конструкцию.

Ну а в справочниках (тех, что встретились мне. За все не ручаюсь) есть только это:

— Пр, — ав. — Пр.

Но, как сами понимаете, здесь авторский текст именно поясняет, комментирует, прямую речь, в то время, как при написании с заглавной буквы, текст автора является отдельным предложением.

Ещё хочу отдельно подчеркнуть, почему считаю скобочки самым неудачным из решений. Используя длинное тире и точки мы чётко показываем где авторский текст, а где прямая речь. Скобочки же не являются знаком препинания, служащим для оформления прямой речи, а потому могут восприниматься читателем как уточнение собственных слов говорящим. Конечно, можно понять из контекста, что в скобочках именно авторская речь, но я бы не рекомендовал настолько усложнять текст для восприятия, а пользоваться уже применяемыми в оформлении художественной литературы средствами.

Answer (score 0):

**Скобки не служат средством отделения прямой речи от слов автора.** Только в цитате скобки, причем квадратные, обозначают авторскую вставку.

Обычные скобки используются для ремарок в пьесах, и текст в них выделяется **курсивом**:

В о л о д я. Мне кажется (*зевает*), что здесь умрешь от скуки.

Еще примечания оформляются в скобках, тоже с **курсивом**:

Мне кажется (зевает. *- Прим. ред.*), что здесь умрешь от скуки.

Просто так вклинить скобки с авторским текстом в прямую речь невозможно.

Правильно:

(1) – Береги Сашеньку, пожалуйста. Ты ему мила, он тебя послушает. - Саша покраснел. - Когда с батюшкой своим встретишься, попроси, чтобы Сашеньку не обидели.

(2) – Петр Иванович, батюшка твой, - она видела, как Саша вздрогнул, - воевал под...

ИЛИ: – Петр Иванович, батюшка твой... - Она видела, как Саша вздрогнул. - ...Воевал под...

(3) Здесь у вас не мысли, как вы пишете, а **реплика** другого лица.

– В России же со слугами без плетки обращаться нельзя.

– Либерал с арапником, – зло прошептал Саша.

– Моль, дрянь беспросветная, человечки, – опять по-русски добавил граф и зыркнул на холопов.

Если бы это были **мысли** другого лица:

– В России же со слугами без плетки обращаться нельзя.

"Либерал с арапником", – подумал Саша.

– Моль, дрянь беспросветная, человечки, – опять по-русски добавил граф и зыркнул на холопов.

Если бы это были **мысли** того же лица внутри его прямой речи:

– В России же со слугами без плетки обращаться нельзя.

"Либерал с арапником", – подумал он.

Моль, дрянь беспросветная, человечки, – опять по-русски добавил граф и зыркнул на холопов.

И не забудьте поставить абзацные отступы перед репликами и мыслями (они здесь не выставляются).

Comment: Предложенное оформление в принципе может использоваться, но в данном тексте оно не смотрится, так как нарушает его динамичность. Для этого текста характерно слитное, а не прерывистое прочтение, а дробное членение на абзацы этого не обеспечивает. И почему в предложении (2) нельзя применить скобки, обозначив вставку? Вставные конструкции могут читаться почти без пауз, выделяясь только понижение общего тона, что также здесь весьма желательно.

Comment: Почему нельзя вставить авторский текст в скобках в прямую речь? Ответ очевиден: потому что это не прямая речь, потому что все смешается. Вставки не используются в прямой речи без спецсредств - курсива или указания на то, что это примечание. Вставки-ремарки характерны для пьес, а не для художественных диалогов - там не ремарки, а слова автора. 
Вариант 3 я оформила по Розенталю. Поспорить можно только по поводу последнего примера: слова - мысли - слова одного человека. Я бы отделяла их абзацем, чтобы не смешивать 2 способа оформления п.р. (именно так делает Розенталь).

Comment: Если оформлять без абзаца, то лучше так: 
- В России же со слугами без плетки обращаться нельзя, - сказал он и подумал: "Либерал с арапником". Так читателю понятнее.

Comment: Как правильно отметил Пересвет, "Скобочки же не являются знаком препинания, служащим для оформления прямой речи, а потому могут восприниматься читателем как уточнение собственных слов говорящим.". Такое оформление нарушает уже сложившиеся правила оформления прямой речи.

Comment: По поводу  скобок ничего определенного сказать пока не могу, но в целом текст с правильным оформлением  выглядит намного хуже исходного варианта. Понятным он был и до редактирования, но еще он был ярким и оригинальным, а стал стандартно-унылым. Думаю, что грамматика прямой речи находится в поисках новых форм, и здесь одним Розенталем уже не обойтись.

Comment: Только про скобочки отметил не Пересвет, а я.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть, для ясности использовать кавычки вместо тире?

"Береги Сашеньку, пожалуйста. Ты ему мила, он тебя послушает". Саша покраснел.  "Когда с батюшкой своим встретишься, попроси, чтобы Сашеньку не обидели".