# Корректна ли такая "двойная" прямая речь?

Tags: прямая-речь

Подскажите, корректно ли написание такое написание прямой речи (из диалога):

> – Я даже не знаю, – начал он издалека, – Жизнь сложная штука, но –
>   поднял он грустный взгляд. – Все равно всё закончится могилой.

Для меня принципиально важно не разбивать ее на 2 разных предложения, поскольку это должно читаться "в одну строчку".

UPDATE: Уважаемые господа и дамы, спасибо за обсуждение. Ну(,) извините меня. Вы придрались к запятой после слов автора, где я совершил ошибку, но смысла вопроса был в "двойной" прямой речи.

> – Я даже не знаю, – начал он издалека. – Жизнь сложная штука, но(,) –
>   поднял он грустный взгляд. – Все равно всё закончится могилой.

Или же так:

> – Я даже не знаю, – начал он издалека, – жизнь сложная штука, но(,) –
>   поднял он грустный взгляд. – Все равно всё закончится могилой.

Оба этих вариантов сути вопроса не меняют.

Однако вопрос запятой после НО (выделил в скобках) - очень интересный вопрос. Ее я ставить не хочу, очень не хочу. Она избыточна и противна!

Comment: Обсуждение  похожего вопроса https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/39735/Сложности-прямой-речи

Comment: Я обновил свой вопрос, спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

**Действия персонажей, авторские замечания** внутри прямой речи могут выделяться **тире или скобками**.

Примеры:

– Что такое Базаров? – Аркадий усмехнулся. – Хотите, дядюшка, я вам скажу, что он, собственно, такое?

– Да, да, я знаю вас, Базаров, – повторила она. (За ней водилась привычка, свойственная многим провинциальным и московским дамам, – с первого дня знакомства звать мужчин по фамилии.) – Хотите сигару?

Можно предложить такой вариант (исходя из определенной интонации и последовательности действий):

**– Я даже не знаю, – начал он издалека, –  жизнь сложная штука, но... (он поднял грустный взгляд) всё равно всё закончится могилой.**

Comment: У вас как речь персонажа выглядит? После "не знаю" какой знак идет? А скобки тут не решают вопрос, да и пример из Тургенева неудачен, мало того, что Тургенев - это по части пунктуации и так мука мученическая, так там еще скобки внутри ***авторского*** текста.

Comment: Дословная речь: Я даже не знаю, жизнь сложная штука, но... всё равно всё закончится могилой.  Хорошо бы еще инверсию добавить: жизнь штука сложная. А примеры из Тургенева я взяла просто потому, что были под рукой. Можно взять любого автора (современного или классического) и посмотреть, как такие вставки оформляют. Мне кажется, что у Розенталя такие случаи не отражены в правилах.

Comment: Arina, про авторские замечания в скобках - у Розенталя не нашел - дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку на источник.

Comment: У Розенталя нет правил для оформления действий персонажей внутри прямой речи, хотя такие варианты встречаются часто. Единственное указание такое:  Если авторские слова, стоящие после прямой речи, представляют собой отдельное предложение, то они начинаются с прописной буквы:— Скорей, загорелась школа! — И он побежал по домам будить людей.   Поэтому проблема существует, требует решения, а официальных правил нет. Соответственно, решение можно найти в печатных изданиях книг, в том числе классиков.

Comment: http://egituman.ru/viewtopic.php?id=1398  Вот еще пример из учебного сайта. Внимание — скользкий момент!
    — В этом сундуке лежали  браслеты. — Я с угрозой обернулся к предателю. — Ещё прадедушкины.
    Две фразы разделены НЕ РЕПЛИКОЙ, а ДЕЙСТВИЕМ, не относящимся к собственно речи, не описывающим её.  Вот такие "скользкие" моменты из-за отсутствия правил. А если неудобно  делить текст на два предложения, то приходится думать о тире и скобках.

Comment: Благодарю, Arina, за интересный вариант со скобками, но он слишком "грузит" взгляд.

Comment: Вариант со скобками очень спорный. Во-первых, он не описан в авторитетных источниках. Во-вторых, не всегда ясно, что стоит в скобках: слова из прямой речи или замечания автора. В-третьих, в нашем примере в одном предложении используются оба приема ( тире и скобки), что вносит дополнительную путаницу.

Comment: 1) Я использовала скобки, потому что в предложении  и так много тире. Чтобы избавиться от них, надо делить предложение на два отдельных, а оно плохо делится. Думаю, чтобы оформить предложение с прямой речью, надо сначала записать только прямую речь  так, как ее видит автор. 2) В данном случае в скобках описано действие персонажа, что здесь можно не понять? 3) Авторитетные источники этой темой практически не занимались, здесь нужно добавлять целую учебную главу, желательно авторитетную.Хотя бы  просто обобщить фактически существующие способы оформления и включить тему в общие  правила.

Answer (score 1):

В таком виде - точно не пойдет.
Во-первых, при таком оформлении не смотрятся заглавные в начале прямой речи после разрывов, особенно вторая. А-во-вторых, точка после слова "взгляд" откуда взялась? Совсем уж сложно будет разобраться со вставкой слов автора после союза "но"... Там запятая нужна бы по правилам, но, согласен, не хочется её там видеть.

По самой идее. Предполагаю, что прямая речь без слов автора выглядит следующим образом: ***"Я даже не знаю. Жизнь сложная штука, но все равно всё закончится могилой."*** Или так: ***"Я даже не знаю... Жизнь сложная штука, но все равно всё закончится могилой."*** Опускаем пока вопрос, зачем это надо лепить в одно предложение, разберемся со знаками на случай хотя бы одного "разрыва".

Если на месте точки или двоеточия надо вставить прямую речь, то записанное в одно предложение это будет выглядеть так.

"Я даже не знаю, - [слова автора]. - Жизнь сложная штука, но все равно всё закончится могилой."

Или

"Я даже не знаю... - [слова автора]. - Жизнь сложная штука, но все равно всё закончится могилой."

Розеньталь:

> 3. Если на месте «разрыва» прямой речи словами автора должна была бы стоять точка, то перед этими словами ставятся запятая и тире, а после
>      них — точка и тире, причем вторая часть прямой речи пишется с
>      прописной буквы...
> 4. Если на месте «разрыва» прямой речи словами автора должно было бы стоять многоточие, то оно сохраняется и после него ставится тире;
>      после слов автора ставятся или запятая и тире (если вторая часть
>      прямой речи не образует самостоятельного предложения, — пишется со
>      строчной буквы):

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=158

Лопатин 
http://orthographia.ru/punctum.php?paragraph=pg135.php

Здесь нужна точка и заглавная в начале второй части прямой речи.

Если еще попытаться как-то перенести правила о разрыве прямой речи словами автора на случай "двукратного" разрыва, то получится примерно следующее.

***"Я даже не знаю, – начал он издалека. – Жизнь сложная штука, но(,) – поднял он грустный взгляд, – все равно всё закончится могилой".***

Не берусь судить, возможно ли оформление без запятой после "но", но в любом случае не могу рекомендовать ни один вариант. Понятно, что случай в "Правилах" не описан и посему приходится ориентироваться на субъективное мнение. А оно лично у меня отрицательное. Смысла вашего "принципиально важно" я не понимаю, а выглядит в результате как-то странно и непривычно.

.---

Ну а ежели вы действительно настаиваете на прямой речи в виде одного предложения, что-то наподобие "Я даже не знаю, жизнь сложная штука, но все равно всё закончится могилой", то не нужна и первая заглавная.

*"Я даже не знаю, – начал он издалека, – жизнь сложная штука, но, – поднял он грустный взгляд, – все равно всё закончится могилой".*

Этот вариант не слишком хорош даже зрительно, хотя хоть как-то объясним с точки зрения правил, чего не скажешь о вашем исходном.

Короче, я бы не экспериментировал с двумя "разрывами". При другой структуре прямой речи оно, возможно, и получится, но не здесь.

.---

По поводу запятой на месте "разрыва". Ну странно это иметь запятую после такого союза, но на основании чего её опустить?

> 2. Если на месте «разрыва» прямой речи словами автора не должно было бы быть никакого знака препинания или должна была бы стоять запятая,
>      точка с запятой, двоеточие либо тире, то слова автора выделяются с
>      обеих сторон запятыми и тире, после которых первое слово пишется со
>      строчной буквы:
>
> «Мы решили, — продолжал заседатель, — с вашего дозволения остаться
>   здесь ночевать» (П.) — на месте «разрыва» не было бы никакого знака;

Розенталь, там же.

У Лопатина есть само это правило, правда нет примера подходящего. 
Каких-то возможных изъятий из общего правил я здесь не вижу.

Comment: Спасибо за старание. Я обновил свой вопрос. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

*– Нет-нет… ни в коем случае. – Страйк с отвращением прислушивался к собственным словам. – На одну неделю – как раз то, что надо. Э-э-э… Вот тут корреспонденция… – Он поднял с коврика кипу писем и бросил их на голый стол как искупительное жертвоприношение. – Будьте добры, просмотрите… отвечайте на телефонные звонки, слегка тут приберите… пароль компьютера – Hatherill-два-три, давайте я запишу… – Он проделал это под ее настороженным, опасливым взглядом. – Вот, держите… Если что – я у себя.* [стр.1]

*– Нет, спасибо, – ответила она глубоким и, как ни странно, мелодичным голосом. – Я понимаю, он злится, – добавила она с непонятным удовлетворением. – Уж как я только его не отговаривала – он и слушать ничего не желает. Похоже, этот, с позволения сказать, детектив ему отказал. И правильно сделал.* [стр.2]
**[Роберт Гэлбрейт. Зов кукушки](http://www.litlib.net/bk/47438/read)** (перевод с английского Елены Петровой)

Если не хочется ставить запятую после "но" (а по правилам знак там нужен!), поставьте троеточие. Выглядеть предложение будет так:

**– Я даже не знаю, – начал он издалека. – Жизнь сложная штука, но... – Поднял он грустный взгляд. – Всё равно всё закончится могилой.**
Или так:
**– Я даже не знаю, – начал он издалека, – жизнь сложная штука. Но... – Поднял он грустный взгляд. – Всё равно всё закончится могилой.**

**Дополнение**
Интересное предложение (со скобками) обнаружилось у того же автора.
Как пример (с купюрами):
***— Здоровенный, чертяка. Вроде тебя, — он стрельнул глазами по массивному торсу Страйка, — только накачанный. — (Страйк безропотно стерпел удар.) — Сразу видно — бывший гангстер.***
[ Получается такая схема: П, — а, — п. — (Действие другого персонажа.) — П.]

Comment: Нет, Римма. Начинать после "но" с большой буквы это совсем плохо... Убивает единую цель.
Тогда уж только так:
– Я даже не знаю, – начал он издалека. – Жизнь сложная штука, но... – поднял он грустный взгляд. – Всё равно всё закончится могилой.

Comment: _Поднял он грустный взгляд_  - законченное самостоятельное предложение, требуется заглавная буква (см. 1 пример). Я просто привела возможные варианты членения.

Comment: @ДенисФедоров Нужен глагол,  связанный с прямой речью. Может быть, так?  – Я даже не знаю, – начал он издалека. – Жизнь сложная штука, но... – запнулся и поднял он грустный взгляд,– всё равно всё закончится могилой. Мне кажется, это что неплохой вариант.

Comment: Пусть будет так, спасибо :-)